# Is it possible to calculate Hamming Distance as a percentage?

Tags: binary

[Hamming Distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_distance) is a way to detect text simlarity. However, Hamming Distance only returns an integer. I wonder if it is possible to calculate Hamming Distance out as a percentage. Thanks

My Python code to calculate Hamming Distance

```
hamming = 0
for i, x in enumerate(FinalString):
    if x != FinalString2[i]:
        hamming += 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can certainly divide the Hamming distance by the length of the string and report the result as a percentage.

Comment: Wouldn't it be 1 - (Hamming Distance) / (Length of string)

Comment: If you want similarity, yes, that would make matching text come out $100\%$.